# datetime format in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

In AngularJs I get a date in this format : ["2018-01-03T09:30:54.264Z"].
I want it to be in the format : "2018-01-03T09:30:00"
How can I get it in this format?

Controller.js

```
var myDate = new Date();
$scope.form.date.push(myDate);
```

template

```
<div class="col-lg-12 photo-container" ng-repeat="photo in selectedPhotos track by $index" ng-if="add">
            <input id="myDate" type="datetime-local" name="date[]" ng-model="form.date[$index]">
            <img ng-src="{{photo}}" class="thumb">
        </div>
```

Comment: You mean _display_ it in that format or _being handled_ in that format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: `<div>{{ form.date[$index] | date : 'yyyy-MM-ddThh-mm-ss' }}</div>`

Comment: Yes, display it in that format. And the date must be an object

Comment: @AlekseySolovey this doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

You are not being clear about how you are doing it, but here is a working example (*work from it*):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('dateCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.form = {
    "date": []
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var myDate = new Date();
    $scope.form.date.push(myDate);
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dateCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="date_ in form.date track by $index">
      <div>1: {{ date_ | date : 'yyyy-MM-ddThh-mm-ss' }}</div>
      <div>2: {{ form.date[$index] | date : 'yyyy-MM-ddThh-mm-ss' }}</div>
      <br/>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment.js to achieve that i.e.

```
var d = moment("2018-01-03T09:30:54.264Z").format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss') .
```

it will give you the required format, put whatever format you want as string in format() function.

Comment: How can i get date with format : '2017-12-31T11:12:00.000Z' ? 
I try this: var d = moment(myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.000Z');
But this doesnt work

Comment: Ok, doesnt matter. I did to do what I wanted

Comment: just use moment().toISOString() you will get ISO format of the date(i.e.-2017-12-31T11:12:00.000Z)

Answer (score 0):

first inject $filter to your controller then try this:

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate = $filter('date')(myDate , "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm"); 
$scope.form.date.push(myDate);
```